# Add contact form

Tags: forms, contact

I want to add contact form to my page. I found http://en.support.wordpress.com/contact-form/ article where (see below) there is button for adding contact form but I don't have this in my Wordpress installation.

[image]

Do I have to add some plugin or what?
I use wordpress 3.3.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are self-hosted, you won't have that button, as that is for Wordpress sites hosted by wordpress.COM

See [The difference between WordPress.com, WordPress, and WordPress.org](http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/)

Search for plugins for self-hosted Wordpress: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=contact+form&sort=

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/ is very popular.